# Update with join with conditions from another table [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm able to select all the records statuses from one table (project_has_tasks) with conditions from another table where progress = 100%

So:

```
select t1.status, t2.progress FROM project_has_tasks t1
left join projects t2
on t1.project_id = t2.id
where t2.progress ='100%' AND t1.project_id ='1'
```

Results I'v got looks as follow:

```
   | status | progress |
   | open   | 100%     |
   | open   | 100%     |
   | to_do  | 100%     |
   | open   | 100%     |
```

What I would like to achieve is to update these results where progress = 100% to done, so the results should looks like that: (after the update):

```
   | status | progress |
   | done   | 100%     |
   | done   | 100%     |
   | done   | 100%     |
   | done   | 100%     |
```

Can you please help me to do that?
Platform: MySQL

Comment: why are you using left join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE project_has_tasks AS t1
left join projects t2 on t1.project_id = t2.id
SET t1.status = 'done'
where t2.progress ='100%' AND t1.project_id ='1'
```

Comment: Works good, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @mariusz.wolski1 - You're welcome, please accept the answer if you found it helpful, by clicking the accept answer button on the left of the answer.